# Problem in boolean

Tags: modifiers

I use the cube and draw this thing. I want to use boolean, but it failed to set value. I use ctrl+shift+alt+m, and i found it highlighted as picture below. How to fix it in order to use boolean modifier to this object? (i tried remove doubles and ctrl+n)[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with boolean? What are you expecting it to do ?

Comment: @GeraldDegeneve I am not sure why my boolean isn't working properly. I watch on YouTube, and it says that my model highlighted got problem and need to fix, but I tried but failed